Grouping rows by overlapping range on Postgresql
I have couple of ranges, which is using postgresql int8range to tell the start and end number. Wondering if there is an SQL query to create a new field group_id to determine if there is an overlapping among these range
For the example below, range (10, 20) and (15, 25) has an overlapping (15, 20), (15, 25) and (20, 30) has an overlapping (20, 25), so (10, 20), (15, 25), and (20, 30) share the same group id 1
Original table



range




(10, 20)


(15, 25)


(20, 30)


(40, 60)


(45, 50)


(90, 99)



Expected output



range
group_id




(10, 20)
1


(15, 25)
1


(20, 30)
1


(40, 60)
2


(45, 50)
2



Got a statement with
https://dbfiddle.uk/4m8VPJ_D
select range, sum(i) over(order by r) as group_id
from (
    select t.*,
    case when range && lag(range) over (order by range) then 0 else 1 end as i
  from t
) x

But seems it does not work with input
https://dbfiddle.uk/hNjK0o6Z

You can use some multirange magic. Assuming that the table is called ranges, the query could be
SELECT range, group_id
FROM (SELECT ranges.range,
             u.o AS group_id,
             count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY u.o) AS group_count
      FROM (SELECT range_agg(range) AS mr
            FROM ranges) AS ra
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(ra.mr) WITH ORDINALITY AS u(r,o)
         JOIN ranges ON u.r @> ranges.range
     ) AS q
WHERE group_count > 1;

  range  │ group_id 
═════════╪══════════
 [11,20) │        1
 [16,25) │        1
 [21,30) │        1
 [41,60) │        2
 [46,50) │        2

First, aggregate all ranges from the table to a single multirange (the subquery ra).
Then, split the multirange into its individual ranges with unnest(). WITH ORDINALITY adds a numbering that we will use as group_id.
Then, join with ranges to see in which group each range lies (@> is the containment operator).
Finally, eliminate all groups that contain only a single member, so don't overlap with other groups.

Thanks! Just found one issue that if we set as [10, 20), [20, 30) then it will treat them as same group although they are 10-19 and 20-29. Wondering how to fix this
https://dbfiddle.uk/IhgPSyLz

There is nothing to fix. The ranges are the same, just displayed in a normalized fashion.
